# How do I create a collision with SpriteKit with an already created SKSpriteNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision, skspritenode

I want the pacman to restart from its original position when it collides with blinky, that is moving.

How can I make them collide considering I have already declared them?

You move the pacman, but blinky moves alone. I want it to work like the pacman game.

```
  public class PacmanScene: SKScene {

let playerSpeed: CGFloat = 40.0
var pacman: SKSpriteNode?
var playerTextures: [SKTexture] = []
var lastTouch: CGPoint? = nil
var blinky: SKSpriteNode?
var clyde: SKSpriteNode?
var inky: SKSpriteNode?
var pinky: SKSpriteNode?
override public init(size: CGSize) {
let pacmanTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "pacman01.png")
    pacman = SKSpriteNode(texture: pacmanTexture)
    pacman?.name = "pacman"

    pacman?.position = CGPoint(x:30, y:30)
    pacman?.zPosition = 1.0
    pacman?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: pacmanTexture, size: CGSize(width: (pacman?.size.width)!, height: (pacman?.size.height)!))
    pacman?.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    pacman?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    pacman?.physicsBody?.mass = 2
 let blinkyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "blinky.png")
    blinky = SKSpriteNode(texture: blinkyTexture)
    blinky?.name = "blinky"

    blinky?.position = CGPoint(x: 15, y: 60)
    blinky?.zPosition = 1.0
    blinky?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: pacmanTexture, size: CGSize(width: (blinky?.size.width)!, height: (blinky?.size.height)!))
    blinky?.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    blinky?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    blinky?.physicsBody?.mass = 1000

    super.init(size: size)
    addChild(pacman!)
    addChild(blinky!)

   override public func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let bmoveUp = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 450, duration: 4.0)

    let bmoveRight = SKAction.moveBy(x:20, y:0, duration: 1.0)

    let bmoveDown = SKAction.moveBy(x:0, y: -450, duration: 4.0)

   let bmoveLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x:-20, y:0, duration: 1.0)


    let bsequence = SKAction.sequence([bmoveUp, bmoveRight, bmoveDown, bmoveLeft])

    let bendlessAction = SKAction.repeatForever(bsequence)
    blinky?.run(bendlessAction)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If iv got this right you want your "blinky" to follow your "pacman" to do this you would have to work out the position of the pacman then add an SKAction to your blinky to move to that position.

Try something like this

```
//Speed blinky moves
let blinkySpeed = 100

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
    updateBlinky()
}

func updateBlinky() {
    //Set the point that blinky moves to
    let point = CGPoint(x: pacman.position.x, y: pacman.position.y)
    //Get the distance its got to travel
    let distance = distanceBetweenPoints(first: pacman.position, second: blinky.position)
    //Get the time is got to take from the speed and distance
    let time = distance / blinkySpeed
    //Create and run the action
    let action = SKAction.move(to: point, duration: TimeInterval(time))
    blinky.run(action)
}

//work out the distance between the sprites
func distanceBetweenPoints(first: CGPoint, second: CGPoint) -> Int {
    return Int(hypot(second.x - first.x, second.y - first.y))
}
```

The end result would be something like this

[image: The end result would be something like this]

Edit:

Okay I think from your question you already have "blinky" moving you just want to detect collisions.

First you need to add the SKPhysicsContactDelegate to your class

```
public class PacmanScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
```

Then you need to add a category bit mask to both the sprites then handle the collisions in didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) method.

What I would do

```
//Create Physics category struct
struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let pacman : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    static var blinky : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
}
```

Then where you are setting up pacman and blinky set the category bitmask

```
//Set the category bit mask for pacman
pacman?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.pacman
//Set what categories you want to test contact
pacman?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.blinky
//Set what categories you want to collide with each other
pacman?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.blinky

//Set the category bit mask for blinky
blinky?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.blinky
//Set what categories you want to test contact
blinky?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.pacman
//Set what categories you want to collide with each other
blinky?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.pacman
```

Then you would need to implement the didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) method to handle the collisions

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    //Work out which contact was pacman
    let other = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.pacman ? contact.bodyB : contact.bodyA
    //Test what it hit
    switch other.categoryBitMask {

        case PhysicsCategory.blinky:
            print("pacman hit blinky")
            //Move pacman
            pacman?.position = CGPoint(x:30, y:30)

        default:
        break

    }
}
```

Hope this helps